# How to solve "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket" error?

Tags: mysql, errors, connections, startup

I kept getting this following error every time I tried to restart MySql. It was working fine before I changed the default data directory.

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib                                                                                                                                                             /mysql/mysql.sock' (111)

I know there are other solutions posted by others but none of them worked for me.

Comment: I got same error how i fixed it in linux. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60557989/7300865

Comment: The catch is you gotta add `socket` variable under `[client]` also, not only `[mysqld]`
Either in a global configuration file or `~/.my.cnf`

Answer (score 15):

Check the folowing

1. First check if another instance is runnig in the same machine

   `ps ax | grep mysql`
2. Then, check if your file my.cnf (probably in /etc/mysql/ folder) is correctly configured with

---

```
[mysqld]
datadir = /var/lib/mysql/
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

3. Next, you have changed the default data directory, did you gave the right permissions to the new directory now

> ```
>  chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql/*
>  chmod 755 -R /var/lib/mysql/*
> ```

4. After changing the permission restart the service and check

   `service mysql restart`

Answer (score 7):

My issue was that multiple mysql processes were running concurrently.

First kill the processes with:

```
sudo pkill mysql
```

and

```
sudo pkill mysqld
```

restart mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

now you should be able to log in

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 5):

It would appear that the socket file is missing. `service mysql stop` and `service mysql restart` depend on the socket file's existence to shutdown.

You will have to connect to mysql using mysqladmin and TCP/IP to shutdown

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-h127.0.0.1 -u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS} --protocol=tcp -P3306"
mysqladmin ${MYSQL_CONN} shutdown
service mysql start
```

[I have posts about shutdowns like this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A877%20protocol%20tcp)

Answer (score 2):

Hi i'have just installed zabbix 3.0 and same problem appeared after few hours ago. When i check the zabbix permission in the phpmyadmin I realised there is no permission for user "zabbix" . I gave Grand permission to zabbix and problem solved. This might be helpfull for someone.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error, but simple reason: system had run out all disk space.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error as well "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib /mysql/mysql.sock' (111)".  I have uninstalled and re-installed MySQl several times and have spent multiple hours troubleshooting the issue.  The issue that I notice is when I added the credentials in the my.cnf option file located in /etc/my.cnf as this will cause MySQL issues with starting the services and would throw the error.

To resolve this, I removed the credentials out of the my.cnf option file in /etc/my.cnf and I create a .my.cnf option file in the home directory.  For example /home/username/.my.cnf in Linux (replace username with your username in Linux) and add the credentials in there.  No issues after that.

Answer (score 0):

Check your mysql service or if you are accessing through ssh try running:

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

Comment: You need to give a little more explanation than just 'do this'.  Providing some simple explanation would be a good start.  Just edit your post and add the explanation.